# Best strategy to dockerize Java with Angular JS applications

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, microservices, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I have a java/AngularJS project that needs to be dockerize for CI/CD process. My project is as below:

```
   Project:
      UI - Angular/Node JS
      Java - Project ABC: 
                  -- Branch: Master
                               -- Service 1 (.jar/war)
                               -- Service 2 (.jar)
                               -- Service 3 (.jar)
```

Should I put all jar/war files into one container/volume? I would like to automate the process as much as possible using CI/CD tools. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

a service is called a micro service only if he can be as a standalone process, meaning it can communicate with other services via socket, fd, pipes etc.. (common and most easy use is socket, often as a higher protocol aka http)

if your services are meeting this criteria than each one of them should be in a different docker container, you can expose any port on any container and because docker maintain a host and dns system you can access each one via the `name_of_container:port` you should look in the [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#prerequisites) docs for more info